# How to remove Master Boot Manager from BIOS

Tags: windows, boot, bios, master

after I spend 2 days like 6 hours per day to figured out and tried all the methods found on the internet I'm put my hope in you guys!

My machine is "Acer Aspire 7 A715-75G" using UEFI Bios. It comes with UEFI SHELL 2.7.

I've installed Microsoft Windows 10 couple of times to figure it out and try to get ride of Microsoft Windows 10 Boot Manager from BIOS. At this moment the HDD is only with UEFI SHELL 2.7 on it as it comes and unallocated space.enter image description here

[BIOS INFO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAqJ7.jpg)

[BIOS MAIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emGrh.jpg)

[BIOS SECURITY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN9Ju.jpg)

[Windows BOOT Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiXsG.jpg)

[UEFI SHELL 2.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWUiN.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The EFI Shell has a `bcfg` command for this purpose:

1. List options using `bcfg boot dump -b`.
2. Remove the unwanted option using `bcfg boot rm ##`.

   (Re-check the full list every time removing *each* option, as the numbers may shift.)

If you have a USB stick with Linux, you can do the same using `efibootmgr`.

Comment: bcfg is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: I installed on a USB memory stick boot-repair-disk-64bit and enter a terminal and I've run those commands: sudo efibootmgr and I saw Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager and run sudo efibootmgr -b 1 -B after that I turn off the laptop and reopen it and the WIndows Boot Manager is still there.